# How to optimize three queries with similar characteristics? (Cypher)

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have an issue on my Neo4j query. In my database for example, I want to select similar people to a person according to his last name, first name and year of birth. If I don't find any one with the exact matching, I will then do a query to find people with same last name and year of birth. Lastly, if I don't find any match for my second query, I will do a third match to find if there are any people how have the same year of birth as the person's. How do I combine this three query into one. I think for a large database, this type of query is very expansive, so I need some way to optimize this logic.

```
MATCH (c:Company)-[r:CARRY]->(p:Person {LastName: "Foo", FirstName: "Bar", YOB: 1999 })
RETURN p
```

If no answers were found I will then do

```
MATCH (c:Company)-[r:CARRY]->(p:Person {LastName: "Foo", YOB: 1999 })
RETURN p
```

If I still can not find an answer, I will try

```
MATCH (c:Company)-[r:CARRY]->(p:Person {YOB: 1999 })
RETURN p
```

I am just trying to make more efficient query for this logic. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query could do the tests in reverse. That is, do the more general tests first.

In step 1 (of the query), you can find all `Person` nodes with the desired `YOB`, which would be a *superset* of the final result. Let's call this set of nodes `p1`.

In step 2, filter the set of nodes in `p1` by the desired `LastName`, and let's call the resulting subset `p2`.

In step 3, filter the set of nodes in `p2` by the desired `FirstName`, and let's call the resulting subset `p3`.

Finally, you can return `p3` if it is not empty, or `p2` if it is not empty, or `p1`.

Here is an example (that assumes the desired `YOB`, `LastName`, and `FirstName` values are passed as [parameters](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/parameters/)):

```
MATCH (:Company)-[:CARRY]->(p:Person)
WHERE p.YOB = $YOB
WITH COLLECT(p) AS p1
WITH p1, REDUCE(s = [], x IN p1 |
  CASE x.LastName WHEN $LastName THEN s + x ELSE s END) AS p2
WITH p1, p2, REDUCE(s = [], x IN p2 |
  CASE x.FirstName WHEN $FirstName THEN s + x ELSE s END) AS p3
RETURN CASE
  WHEN SIZE(p3) > 0 THEN p3
  WHEN SIZE(p2) > 0 THEN p2
  ELSE p1 END AS result
```

[UPDATE]

If you want to limit the maximum size of the `result` list, just change the last line of the query to:

```
  ELSE p1 END[..$limit] AS result
```

where `limit` is assumed to be a parameter.

Comment: Thank you very much! but a little typo here the las else should return p1 right?

Comment: Yes, and I have fixed my answer. Glad it works for you.

Comment: If I want to apply a LIMIT here, it seems not working. Do you know how I can do that?